# $A$ is equipotent with $B$, $a\in A, b\in B$, then $A-\{ a\}$ is equipotent with $B-\{ b\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following equipotence
If $A$ is equipotent with $B$, $a\in A, b\in B$, then $A-\{ a\}$ is equipotent with $B-\{ b\}$

I know the easiest way would be to show that the function going from
  $A-\{ a\}$ to $B-\{ b\}$ is bijective. But I have no idea on how to start. Any help wod be appreciated.

Comment: *The* function? Which function? You may only assume there is a bijective function from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: And suitably modify it to get a bijective function from $A\setminus\{a\}$ to $B\setminus\{b\}$.

Comment: A bit more detailed hint: You already now that a bijection $f:A\to B$ exists. But you don't know if $f(a)=b$, so this doesn't necerssarily give you a bijection $f:A-\{a\}\to B-\{b\}$. But you do know that this is a bijection from $f:A-\{a\}\to B-\{f(a)\}$. Can you find a bijection between $B-\{f(a)\}$ and $B-\{b\}$?

Comment: @user160738 Thank you for the detailed hint. I understand that if we define $g: B-\{f(a)\} \rightarrow B-\{b\}$, then showing that the composite function $f \circ g$ is bijective will prove the statement. But we are talking about the case $f(a)$ not being equal to $b$ So $f(a)=b'$ for some $b' \in B$. I am stuck here. Could you help me a little bit more thank you..

Comment: @CrusoJames What is the most basic bijection you can think of? It's identity map. But problem is that identity maps $b'$ to $b'$. Let's not think about these two points $b'$ and $b$ first, and we do have a bijection on $B-\{b',b\}$ which is just identity. Now just map $b\in B-\{f(a)\}$ to $b'\in B-\{b\}$ and this gives required bijection

Answer (score 3):

If $A$  is equipotent with $B$, there is a bjective map $\psi: A \to B$ by definition of *equipotent*. Let $a \in A$ and $b\in B$.

Define $A' := A\setminus \{a\}$ and $B' := B\setminus \{b\}$

Case 1: If $\psi(a) = b$, then the restriction of $\psi$ to $\psi|_{A'}: A' \to B'$ via $x \mapsto \psi(x)$ is again a bijection from $A'$ to $B'$.

Case 2: If $\psi(a) \not= b$, then $\psi(a) = b' \in B'$. Moreover, there is an element $a' \in A'$ with $\psi(a') = b$ because $\psi$ is bijective. We define another bijective map $\eta: A \to B$ via $\eta(a) := b$ and $\eta(a') = b'$ and $\eta(x) := \psi(x)$ for $x \in A\setminus \{a,a'\}$. Then go to case 1 with $\eta$ instead of $\psi$.